# Heightmap, how can i prevent bad odd numbers

Tags: heightmap

I am building my world-editor for my game. I've noticed, that, no matter how i implement the heightmap, i'll end up with dumb odd numbers in calculations.

For example, lets take a HeightMap of 4x4 which covers a area of 2x2 OpenGL-Units. Thats a small image which shows the problem. The **black** lines and numbers represent units in OpenGL, the **red** lines and numbers repesent pixel/values on my heightmap.

[image]

You can easily see, that in the top image, every number is really odd and i actually need a lot of additional code to calculate everything correctly (OpenGL-position -> heightmap-pixel and heightmap-pixel -> OpenGL-position).

In the bottom image however, i am missing height-values for the right and the bottom row of vertices.

I thought i could just use +1 pixel for every heightmap, this would solve this problem but i am sure it will introduce problems at other ends.

How would you guys handle this?

---

As stated in the comments, the real problem here is, that i need to calculate OpenGL-position -> heightmap-position and OpenGL-range -> heightmap-range fairly often to *draw* on the heightmap and the math gets really hard to handle with the mapping as seen in the top-image.

Comment: Use a 5x5 heightmap?

Comment: Yes, but as i said in my second last sentence: `this would solve this problem but i am sure it will introduce problems at other ends.`

Comment: Which problems are you sure it will introduce?

Comment: Why doesn't the size of the height-map correspond to the number of vertices in your terrain mesh?

Comment: @FuzzyLogic it does, at the moment it looks like the top image in my question.

Comment: So you have a height-map of 4x4 pixels and you want to map it to a mesh plane of 4x4 vertices? So what does world units have to do with it? Create your mesh with each vertex 1 unit apart, then scale your mesh to the desired final size. Can't say I really understand what the issue is. Sounds like you are trying to build a mesh on the fly, to exact final dimensions, then you will run into the sort of problem you described.

Comment: @FuzzyLogic yes, i am trying to create the mesh 'on the fly' to final dimensions. The Problem is, this is for a world-editor, therefore i need to do a lot of calculations from absolute GL-coordinates to heightmap-coordinates and back (higher terrain, lower terrain, draw texture, and so on). Therefore, no matter how i *build* the mesh, at the end i have to do a lot of dirty calculations to get the correct positions.

Comment: Something about what you are doing outside of anything you are showing us is where your problem is.  You aren't really making a lot of sense so its hard to help you out. Could you try explaining a little better?

Comment: What I'm gathering is that you want to do something like painting with a terrain brush, but then you are having trouble mapping the mouse positions in world coords back to the height-map? On the right track?

Comment: @FuzzyLogic exactly. Not only that, since i not only want to higher/lower a single coordinate, i need to calculate a pixel-radius from my opengl-unit-radius, the middle pixel in the heightmap, thats just so much stuff to calculate and it gets worse with those weird height-map<->opengl mappings as seen in the top image.

Comment: Ok, that's much clearer then. Please update your question to clarify what the problem is for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in World Units -> Heightmap. Think in World Units -> Model Units -> Heightmap. This is called normalization.

You will need to normalize from world units back to your model units *before* you try to map to the heightmap and vice versa. You can do this with some simple scale-factor, assuming that the vertices in your terrain mesh are uniform distance of 1 unit apart from each other.

Lets say you have a terrain mesh that is 100x100 vertices and a height-map that is 100x100 pixels, but you want the terrain to be 257x257 units.

Now, when you are painting with the terrain brush, you will find the world coords from your mouse position, then scale that position back down to your model units, so you get a 1:1 mapping with your height-map.

In this example, the model scale is 100units but the world scale is 257units, so that is a scale factor of 2.57

Let's say that you click on the position at {183,183,z} in world units. So divide by 2.57 and you get 71.206226... rounded, that would be vertex[71][71] (but don't round yet).

You will need to do this for the brush size as well, if the brush size is 3 world units in diameter, then divide by 2.57 and you get a model unit size of 1.167315... for your brush diameter. Knowing this, you can work on the vertices and pixels within a radius of (1.167315/2.0) from {71.206226, 71.206226}. If your brush were square, that would be {70.622568, 70.622568} to {71.789884, 71.789884}

Once you determine the bounds of your brush in model units, then you round to integer so you can index the vertices or heightmap.

Hope that helps.